# Does update action have instance variables in edit method? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does update action have instance variables in edit method?

I’m developing a form with validation, and would like to render edit form without deleting existing inputs. However, I got nill for the instance variables in edit form.
Are there any way to keep instance variables?

```rb
def update 
  render ‘edit’ and return unless account.update(params)
end

def edit
  @name = Account.find(params[:id]
end
```

Comment: The docs on [Updating an Article](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#updating-an-article) from the _Getting Started with Rails_ guide might help to understand how a Rails controller typically works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

When your Rails server gets a request the router tries to match it a route and the corresponding controller/action combo. The router then instanciates the controller class with the request as input and calls the method matching the route definition on it.

Since each request is processed by a separate instance of the controller class it's impossible to share instance variables. Neither is it something you actually want to do - processing each request in isolation makes it a lot less error prone.

Instead what is conventionally done in Rails is to use `before_action` to define a callback to setup the instance variables:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /accounts/1/edit 
  # this method can actually be omitted completely
  # rails will implicitly render the view if found
  def edit
  end

  # PATCH /accounts/1
  def update
    if @account.update(account_params)
      redirect_to @account, 
        success: 'Account updated'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # ...
  private

  def set_account
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  end

  def account_params
    params.require(:account)
          .permit(:name, :foo, :bar, :baz)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does update action have instance variables in edit method?

No, here's why:

1. You make a request to `edit`, and rails would make an instance of your controller (where you set @name)
2. you submit your form, which is a new request handled by Rails, which will make a (new) instance of your controller.

you can probably get what you want like this:

```rb
def update 
  @name = account.name # I'm guessing, here, because accessing `name` in the edit action seems to be cut
  render ‘edit’ and return unless account.update(params)
end

def edit
  @name = Account.find(params[:id]
end
```

But a more canonical way would be to save an account instance in the variable

```
@account = Account.find(params[:id])
```

And use it in the view (like `form_for @account`). But this may or may not fit your use case.